# Irrationality of $\pi+c$

Tags: irrational-numbers, constants

How to prove that $\pi+c$ is irrational?

where $c$ is the  [Champernowne Constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant).

Comment: What makes you think it is irrational? What makes you think it is known whether it is irrational?

Comment: @GerryMyerson @ vito Both $\pi$ and $c$ can be written as infinite series. Maybe there is some way to add them together and prove that the resulting series is also irrational.

Comment: I doubt this is known. (Of course, if $\pi+c$ were rational, this would make the calculation of the digits of $\pi$ _much_ easier.) On a related note, it also has not been proven whether or not $\pi+e$ is irrational.

Comment: @ghosts, every number can be written as an infinite series.

Answer (score 0):

That is still an open problem.